# Multiple FeatureType in WFS Protocol

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver

I would like to pass multiple featureTypes to WFS protocol in order to accomplish a search feature in my app. the idea worked just fine with one featureType, but now I need to add another one to expand my search scope. Here is what I did:

```
var featureTypes = ["Layer_1", "Layer_2"];  

var wfsProtocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.v1_1_0({ 
             url: URL,                 
             featureType: featureTypes,
             featureNS: "http://mapmap.org", 
             srsName: "EPSG:3857", 
             version: "1.1.0", 
             extractAttributes: true, 
             isBaseLayer: false, 
             visibility: true 
               });


wfsProtocol.read({            
    filter: filter,                      
    callback: processTheQuery, 
    scope: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed({preload: true})],
         })
```

But still didn't work, Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

just combining the two layers in one by UNION. It works for me.